# Divide insert query into multiple queries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-insert

I have a SP that combines data according to several rules inside. now i have to run my SP for last 3 years but it takes 30 minutes to run for one month. so i multiplied SP code (i.e. SP_2019, SP_2018, SP_2019) and these SPs insert into each table of years (tbl_2018,tbl_2019,tbl_2020). my plan was inserting these 3 tables into my final target table after all calculations done with separately.

after that i run this 3 SPs in different sessions same time one month (201801,201901,202001) now each one takes 65-70 minutes.

why did it increased? because of all 3 SPs use same source tables? i expected that all sessions end in 30 min.

Comment: You'd have to show us the SP code and/or the execution plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)  Check out this, it may have some relevance? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dput2VvuY1w

Comment: These symptoms are expected if you have CPU or IO bandwidth/IOPS resource constraints. Running 3 parallel process instead of 1 won't improve throughput in that case. To improve performance, start with and query index tuning if you haven't already done so.

Comment: your guess is kinda true. share your code and plan so we can optimize it.